# Tkinter image label not appearing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have no idea why this doesn't work. I'm using python 3 on a mac. I have tried
label.image but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
File=open("/Users/user/Desktop/Python/File.txt")
FileContents=File.readlines()
ThingAmount=Team[0]
ActiveThing=Team[1]
ActiveThingImage=PhotoImage("/Users/user/Desktop/Python/"+ActiveThing+"/"+ActiveThing+".gif")
EnemyThingImage=PhotoImage("/Users/user/Desktop/Python/Enemy/EnemyThing.gif")
ActiveThingLabel=Label(window,image=ActiveThingImage)
ActiveThingLabel.image=ActiveThingImage
ActiveThingLabel.place(x=0,y=0)
EnemyThingLabel=Label(window,image=EnemyThingImage)
EnemyThingLabel.place(x=100,y=100)
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  A small block of code floating in the air isn't enough to go on.

Comment: Is the code you posted here identical to your local code?  It looks like you're missing a `"` quote in the `ActiveThingImage=` line

Comment: @BryanOakley that is as minimal complete and verifiable as i can get it

Comment: What's complete about it? If I run it I get multiple errors. For example, you don't have any imports, you have unbalanced quotes, you don't call `mainloop`, you don't create a root window, and the variables `window`, `Team`,  and `Active_Pokemon_Sprint" are undefined,  just to name the most obvious problems.

Comment: @BryanOakley first of all, its obvious that i do imports and window, that's standard, secondly, I messed up some of the variables, my bad, just tell me instead of linking an unhelpful article. I remember now why i stopped using stackoverflow in the first place.

Comment: Part of the problem could be that this code is in a function and you're not calling the function, or you're calling it but other widgets have higher priority so they are hiding the window, or the window that these widgets is in is not visible, or you have two functions with the same name, or there could be several other reasons. This is why we need to see enough code to reproduce the problem. Often, the effort you put into creating the [mcve] is enough for you to solve your own problem. Creating a MCVE isn't a stackoverflow thing, it's a common tool used by experienced programmers.

Comment: @BloodPanther The article linked isn't *"unhelpful"*, it's one of the best tools you have to get an answer here on Stack Overflow. Most people who answer questions here on SO will only spend a decent amount of time looking at your issue if you've got to the effort of putting it into a clear, complete and concise format for them to review. This is pretty standard and isn't asking much of you. Unfortunately, if you want the best chance at getting your question answered, you need to play by the rules. All I'm saying is there's a reason this post has 3 downvotes.

Comment: Yep, now I remember why I hate this website.

Comment: We would love to help. We can't help if we can't reproduce the problem, it's as simple as that. You presented code that has at least half a dozen problems. The fact is, if we make educated guesses about the missing code, your code works fine. Most likely, the reason your label isn't showing is because of code that you are not showing us. If you want help, you need to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

images can be slightly tricky - but I think I can help with 2 answers!

> 1. creates the image
> 2. how to load a bunch of images from a folder somewhere.

1:

getting the buttons to have an image can be kind of tricky (you kind of need a 2 layered approach), but changing the image is easy.

```
x_image = 'x.png'

o_image = 'o.png'
```

then...

```
x_image_for_button = PhotoImage(file=x_image)
o_image_for_button = PhotoImage(file=o_image)
```

then.....

```
button = tk.Button(self.controller, image=o_image_for_button, command=lambda: command_or_something)
button.config(width="40", height="40")
button.place(x=5, y=5)
```

(add in self. or root. etc)

now all you do to change the image is:

```
button.set(image=o_image_for_button)
#on second thought... maybe use `button.config(image=o_image_for_button)` insted
```

2:

```
image_folder = 'theme_icons'
if self.controller.background_theme == '1':
    image_pathway = 'classic'

elif self.controller.background_theme == '2':
    image_pathway = 'blue1'

elif self.controller.background_theme == '3':
    image_pathway = 'blue2'

elif self.controller.background_theme == '4':
    image_pathway = 'classic_blue'


self.house_image_d = os.path.join(image_folder, image_pathway, 'Image1.png')
self.line_d = os.path.join(image_folder, image_pathway, 'Image2.png')


self.house_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.house_image_d)
self.my_line = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.line_d)
```